# Rails invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) - Heroku crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My app is crashing on Heroku, here is the log:

```
pp/helpers/application_helper(bg).rb:70: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (Synt
axError)
←[36m2011-09-15T18:48:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m /app/app/helpers/application_help
er(bg).rb:71: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

A part of the application helper(bg):

```
def convert_html_entities(text)
    text.gsub(/&aring;/,"å") - Line 70
    text.gsub(/&aelig;/,"æ")
    text.gsub(/&oslash;/,"ø")   
    text.gsub(/&copy;/,"©")         
end
```

I have tried to safe the helper file as UTF-8 and it did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have the line

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

as the first line of your file. If the file is saved in a different encoding substitute that for `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using a different ruby version on my heroku stack than on my devel machine. Transfered stacks and it worked.